# Postman generating wrong authorization code while giving username and password under basic auth

Tags: spring-boot, post, postman, authorization

While hitting the post request of an API through Postman and selecting basic auth, then putting in the username and password, I'm getting a 401 unauthorized response. Upon debugging, I checked that the same API is working fine through Talend API tester, but not in Postman. Furthermore, if I directly put the authorization header in Postman with the value generated in Talend AT, then it works fine.

So, I assume that Postman is generating the wrong AuthCode unlike TalendAT in the header section of the request when selecting basic auth and putting in the same username and password. Can someone help me to understand why this is happening?

[image: TalendAT AuthCode image]

[image: Postman AuthCode image]

Comment: i am putting username password under authorization tab only in postman, while pasting screen shot kept headers tab open for comparison

Comment: Can you share the local auth server code? It can reproduce your problem.

Comment: for same username password postman generating Basic anAKOmphdml5YQ== rather Basic anA6amF2aXlh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anA6amF2aXlh decoded is -> jp:javiya

anAKOmphdml5YQ== decoded is -> jp:javiya same but with line break in the middle.

make sure you didn't paste some space or some wrong character in postman.

you can use https://www.base64decode.org/